# PHP Regular expression - strip everything except alphanumeric, space, dash, and @ sign

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently using this to remove unwanted characters:

```
    $pattern        = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .]*";
    $form_lookup    = @ereg_replace($pattern, '', $form_lookup);
```

How can I include/allow the @ sign?

These seem not to work as expected:

```
$pattern        = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .\@]*";
$pattern        = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .@]*";
```

Comment: Why you are using `ereg_*`?

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: @RahilWazir: Because he is an ugly peacekeeper.

Comment: Where's the subject string ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte wins half of a frelling cracker.  The prize is lessened by the incorrect assumption that I am male.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `ereg_replace` use `preg_replace`:

```
$form_lookup    = 'foo@!:_;';
$pattern        = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ .@]*/';
$form_lookup    = preg_replace($pattern, '', $form_lookup);
```

Output:

```
string 'foo@_' (length=5)
```

Comment: ereg_replace has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. See the documentation: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/[^\w\s@-.]/
```

And use `preg_*` and not `ereg_*` asi it is deprecated

Comment: Missing the period from the OP's expression.